# What is a good test for an iPhone developer?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I would like to outsource some work to remote iPhone developers.  However, I don't actually program in Objective-c myself, I was wondering if anyone could suggest a test I could give potential developers to test their skills/knowledge of both Objective-c, Xcode etc.  Possibly a few questions with answers or whether there already exists something.  It would be really good if I could ask these questions directly in an online chat to see what their responses are without them having to refer to books (or colleagues).

Comment: Good developers use books/references/google. You seem to avoid those people :)

Comment: check out stackoverflows career board

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should google around for some good iPhone development questions.

Secondly do some background check on the potential developers you want to hire like their activities on site like SO...What's their reputation,do they answer good questions etc... I do the same before conducting interview of a candidiate...

Cheers